# Replace ending on multiple img src

Tags: javascript

I have 10 buttons each with a different image and text. I have each button to click on/off and if another button is clicked I want the active button to turn off. I am struggling with the latter.

```
var x = 300;

//port1
    $('#port1').click(
    function(){
        var src = $('.image', this).attr('src');
        //var srcs = $(this).attr('src');
        if($(this).hasClass("highlight")) {  
            $('.butt').removeClass('highlight');
            $('.image', this).attr('src', src.replace(/_dark(\.[^.]+)?$/, '_light$1'));
            $('.p1').fadeOut(x);
        }
        else{
            $('.butt').removeClass('highlight');
        //  $('.butt').attr('src').replace('_dark.png', '_light.png');
            $('.butt img').each(function() {
                var src2 = $('.image').attr('src').replace(/_dark(\.[^.]+)?$/, '_light$1');
                $('.image').attr('src', src2);
            });
            $('.talk').fadeOut(x);
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
            $('.image', this).attr('src', src.replace(/_light(\.[^.]+)?$/, '_dark$1'));
            $('.p0').fadeOut(x);
            $('.p1').fadeIn(x);
     }  
});
```

The problem I am running into is that when I click the button, it changes the src on all the other buttons to be exactly the same as this one and does not just change the ending on the other sources to '_dark'. I thought adding this 'each' function would help and it did not.

Edit: I am new to coding but i attempted a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/messedUP90/yxjoxe41/
The random computers that appear was the effect I am going for and the code I wrote to do it before I remembered that each icon was going to be different. Look at the first button titled "un" for where the error I am talking about happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gtf1dk0m/1/

You need to re-set the variable src.

This code does it:

```
$('.butt').each( function( index ) {
    if ( $(this).attr('src') ) {
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/_dark(\.[^.]+)?$/, '_light$1'));
    } 
});
```

ignore the fact that the image does not change color in the jsfiddle. it works in dreamweaver. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is some strange code and naming conventions in this function... such as `var src = $('.image', this).attr('src');`... theres a lot unexplained by the question asked here and with no jsfiddle it's hard to imagine what you mean or see what HTML elements you're using...

so I will try to answer based on purely your description and not your code.

If you want to remove all instances of a class such as an active class you could simply do an `each` function however your later comments about it changing all other image sources once clicked is in this line `$('.image').attr('src', src2);`. You have effectively targeted all images under the class `.butt` which seems to be all of your images. Perhaps what you want is actually to iterate over all elements and remove the active state such as...

```
$(".butt img").each(function() {
    //Remove Active Classes
    if($(this).hasClass("activeImage")) {
        $(this).removeClass("activeImage");
    }
});
```

Then you are now free to take the clicked button and add its active state in...

```
$(".buttons").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        //Old Code
        $(".butt img").each(function() {
            //Remove Active Classes
            if($(this).hasClass("activeImage")) {
                $(this).removeClass("activeImage");
            }
        });
        //New Code
        $(this).addClass("activeImage");
    });
});
```

Then in your CSS you could make sure that you have a rule like

```
.activeImage {
    background-image: url("blah.png") !important;
    /* You Get The Idea */
}
```

Comment: I attempted a jsfiddle. i hope this works: http://jsfiddle.net/messedUP90/yxjoxe41/ 

i had previously attempted a separate div with the background img as the icons... but i decided against it. i do not remember why. is this what you would recommend?

Comment: yes and no. Your example seems to be working just fine the only thing to remember is that the more lines of code your script has, the more times it has to be downloaded... by everyone. So try to do clever things with JQuery that target a lot of things at once. You have a lot of things the same in each `.click()` function in your fiddle so each one doesn't need to be selected by id `$("#")`. Instead target all of them at once and in each callback refer to itself with `$(this)`